# Following the firebase documentation, .update is still overwriting

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am following [this guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data?authuser=0) and [this reference document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference?authuser=0#update) to try and update a node with key/values where the key is pushID's generated elsewhere. I have tried it several different ways and it always overwrites any existing pushID keys, but it doesn't mess with other non-pushID key/value pairs on the same parent. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong? I should also note that this is being run in the firebase cloud functions--Here's the code

Here's the code of what I tried:

```
const parentNode = "zzABCDEFG" //this is an internal reference that I must use

const parentNodeRef = admin.database().ref().child(parentNode)

const PushIDSnap = await admin.database().ref('/ref/to/another/pushID/elsewhere').once('value')

const PushIDSnapVal = PushIDSnap.val() //getting the pushID that I want to set as the key

await parentNodeRef.child(PushIDSnapVal).set(Data)
```

I have also tried:

```
const obj = {}

obj[PushIDSnapVal] = Data

console.log(obj) //console in firebase cloud-functions correctly shows { '-LH9-nBF6Wx3g6oSq154': '-LHBg3xKC51qYG6WAq65*FL' }

await parentNodeRef.update(obj) //this does the same thing--overwrites any existing AND DIFFERENT pushID's that are children of the parentNode
```

also tried, similar to the above but using the full path--works the same as the other two

```
const obj = {}

const key = '/' + parentNode + '/' + PushIDSnapVal

obj[key] = Data

console.log(obj) //console in firebase cloud-functions correctly shows { '/ACGDIQCZZ/-LH9-nBF6Wx3g6oSq154': '-LHBg3xKC51qYG6WAq65*FL' }

await admin.database().ref().update(obj) //this does the same thing--overwrites any existing AND DIFFERENT pushID's that are children of the parentNode
```

Here's the JSON tree of what I am getting (copied directly from the export file in the firebase console):

```
"zzACGAFCG" : {

    "-LHA_9g4U8GzpjxiJmpa" : "-LHGXaRWxHhpWHeGk5Ob^MB", 

    "tT" : "D"

},
```

when I run it again with a different pushID it overwrites just the first key/value pair and doesn't mess with the 'tT' child node

Here's what I want:

```
"zzACGAFCG" : {

    "-LHA_9g4U8GzpjxiJmpa" : "-LHGXaRWxHhpWHeGk5Ob^MB", 

    "-LH9-nBF6Wx3g6oSq154" : "-LHFN0BZ2FNWUExOnulR^NA",

    "tT" : "D"

},
```

When I run it again with a different pushID it should add the new key/value pair and keep the old one.

Answer (score 1):

To get from what you have to what you want, you need to run this update:

```
var ref = firebase.database.ref("zzACGAFCG");
ref.update({ "-LH9-nBF6Wx3g6oSq154": "-LHFN0BZ2FNWUExOnulR^NA" });
```

This is as minimal as it can be, so I assume you'll need to do some more work in your code to get here. I'll give you some background information on how multi-location updates work below.

---

The most important thing to realize is that an update statement loops over all the keys/paths in the object you provider and essentially performs a `set` operation on each of those.

Say you have the following JSON:

```
{
  "root": {
    "messages": {
      "message1": "blablabla",
      "message2": "blablabla"
    }
  }
}
```

If you run this update statement:

```
var root = firebase.database().ref("root");
root.update({ messages: { message3: "new message" } });
```

Then the entire `/root/messages` node will be replaced with the update, so the result will be:

```
{
  "root": {
    "messages": {
      "message3": "new message"
    }
  }
}
```

As I said, beyond the first level of keys/paths in your update objects, the database performs a `set()` operation. It doesn't do a deep merge.

If you want to patch a node on a lower level, you need to ensure that you have the entire path of the property you want to update in the key of the update object. So:

```
root.update({ "messages/message3": "new message" });
```

Will result in:

```
{
  "root": {
    "messages": {
      "message1": "blablabla",
      "message2": "blablabla",
      "message3": "new message"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: that's exactly how I have tried it--see the 2nd block of code in my post. I have to set it up as obj[key] = data, because there is no way for me to write out the pushID since the string of the key is being set at runtime. The object is being evaluated identical to what you have in your code as confirmed by what the console.log is showing in firebase. What makes it even more odd is that it isn't overwriting the entire node. To use your example with messages, it is overwriting message1 with message3, but leaving message2 still there. I get how the .update function works-it isn't working right

Comment: I'm having a hard time parsing the code in your question, which is why I went with a simplified example in my answer. See if you can reproduce it with hardcoded values for e.g. `PushIDSnapVal`. If you can, set up something like a jsbin that reproduces it and I'll have a look.

Comment: ok thanks, I've got to head out of town and probably won't be able to do anything further until Tuesday or Wednesday of next week. Basically I am pulling a pushID from another location in the database and setting it up as a key under a different parent with a string value assigned to it. (In this case the string is another pushID, which is why it probably looks a little confusing.) Maybe there is a better way to set it up. I have done .update using the written out form like .update({ "key": "value"}) and it has always worked perfectly, so I don't understand why passing an object doesn't work

Comment: As I said and showed: most likely you need to pull part of the object into your key. But the code you shared looks fine. Let me know once you set up a repro, and I'll have a look.

Comment: I reproduced it using hard-coded strings for the pushIDSnapVal and Data variables. It is doing exactly the same as when I pulled their information using the .once and .val functions. Here is a link to the jsbin of the code used in reproducing it: https://jsbin.com/hedarif/edit?html,js,output

Comment: I apologize if I didn't set that up right in jsbin, I was thinking that you only wanted the new code, but if you need something else let me know. Again, I appreciate your help.